# React Native IOS SDK Version issue

Tags: ios, reactjs, xcode, react-native, testflight

I have Macbook Air with OS 12.7.3 (latest one after this Apple doesn't show any update) and the Xcode version 14. I have a issue while pushing my archive build of react native app to TestFlight and App Store Connect, but it is getting rejected to due to SDK version as my current version is 16 and it asking for 16.1 and to do that i need to upgrade my Xcode and to upgrade the Xcode i need to upgrade my OS to 13.5 version as required by Xcode and I cannot upgrade to 13.5 version as i do not have that latest update from apple for my macbook air. So i would need to buy a new Mac Device which not feasible right now for me. So is there any feasible solution for it deploy on TestFlight?

I tried using Xcode Cloud but the issue still persist, so is there any other way to push the app to TestFlight or Manage the SDK build so that App Store Connect accepts it. And I can deploy it on TestFlight and App Store.

[click on the link to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MRDr.png)

Answer (score 0):

- Unfortunately, there is no alternative solution to deploy your app on TestFlight without upgrading your Xcode and OS version. The issue you're facing is due to the SDK version of your app, which is not compatible with the App Store Connect requirements.
- The only way to resolve this issue is by upgrading your Xcode to version 14.1 or later, which requires upgrading your OS to 13.5 or later. As you mentioned, you cannot upgrade your OS to 13.5 due to the lack of the latest update from Apple for your MacBook Air.